# Rails API only configuration NGINX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

On Amazon, linux have Nginx running with a rails application. All Good.
Added a Rails API application (API only with routes starting as /api/v1/xxxxx)

Nginx configuration for the API

```
upstream cb_api {
  server unix:///var/www/html/counterpoint-api/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/html/counterpoint-api/public;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name cb-api.ariki.online;

  location ~ ^api/v1/(.+)$ {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass http://cb_api;
       #proxy_redirect off;
  }


}
```

I've tried all variations I could think of but always getting a 403 error from Nginx.

Does someone have a working example configuration?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

You can simply redirect to port 3000 (where rails are running) on your ^api/v1/(.+)$

This is the most easy option:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name cb-api.ariki.online;

    location ~ ^api/v1/(.+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Then, start your rails app in the 3000 port.

## Option 2

Create a configuration file in your app:

$ touch /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/config/nginx.conf

Add the content below in your configuration file:

$ sudo vim /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/config/nginx.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/tmp/sockets/your_linux_user-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/public;
  access_log /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

then create a link to your conf and start nginx:

$ sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

$ sudo ln -nfs /home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_app_name

$ sudo service nginx start

finally, run puma creating the socket file:

$ puma -b unix:///home/your_linux_user/your_app_name/tmp/sockets/your_app_name-puma.sock